# In what category does my problem fall machine learning or deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, tensor

I have two year data that generated from the slot game and i had stored that data in .csv file according to date format as shown below:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date </th>
    <th>Spins </th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>1/1/2018</td>
    <td>300234 </td>
  </tr>
  
   <tr>
    <td>2/1/2018</td>
    <td>400234 </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>.......</td>
    <td>....... </td>
  </tr>
  
    <tr>
    <td>.......</td>
    <td>....... </td>
  </tr>
  
    <tr>
    <td>.......</td>
    <td>....... </td>
  </tr>
  
   <tr>
    <td>18/6/2019</td>
    <td>400234 </td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```

so i want to predict spins on a particular day how can i do it ?

i know i don't have enough feature to build any kind of model but just suppose if i have the enough data and features so in which category does my problem fall machine learning or deep learning?

i had tried linear model of sklearn although after that i get to know that won't work for date related data so i tried Facebook prophet model for time series forecasting model. but that also didn't work. i'm also learning tensor-flow and i'm in a doubt that it will also not work as it is for deep learning.

i'm newbie in this kind of thing so just some guidance would be help full

when i give any date(future date) it should return predicted spins.

Comment: sorry for the HTML code i never asked any question on stackoverflow .

Comment: Before you apply any machine learning approach, why do you think that number of spins is predictable? Can you plot the spins vs date and see if there is a pattern?

Comment: thanks for the response, so you are saying number of spins is not predictable?

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, the type of problem you're trying to solve is called [Supervised Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning). You have a bunch of input-output pairs, and you want the model to learn to extrapolate this pattern to unseen data.

Comment: okay i got it , correct me if i'm wrong "this problem can't be solved with linear models of scikit learn and it's also not a classification problem".

so which model can solve this kind of problem??

Answer (score 0):

Hey @shubham Hello to the stack-overflow community. Firstly we have to see that if our problem is solved through machine learning algorithms than we preferred machine learning because all the machine learning algorithm is completely build in different library. Most common library is sklearn. You have tabular data so I recommend you to use Machine learning Algorithm.

Provide more information so that people in stack overflow community able to understand what is the nature of your data.

When we Use Deep Learning:

- When we have unstructured data(images , Natural Text, time Series
  data,videos etc)
- When we have a lot of data (min 4K records) for training.

When we use Machine Learning

- For tabular data (columns and rows)
- Machine learning Algorithms work for small number of data.

  [For More Information see this](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/deep-learning.html)

For viewing different Projects of Machine Learning and deep learning see this.

[Compare Machine Learning Classifiers At once(Breast Cancer Kaggle Notebook)](https://www.kaggle.com/sohaibanwaar1203/cancer-diagnoses-0-97-accuracy)

Comment: thanks for the response. i was actually wondering that is it possible to predict total Spins of future date/week/month in slot game if i have data like i mentioned in my question?

Comment: is their any-other column  except date/week/month because I don't think so their is any co relation in these column. one other method is to separate date, month and week. date will be (1-30)  week(1-4) month(1-12) than according to these 3 column you will be able to use machine learning algorithms, and their are less number of columns i.e only 3 so deep learning will not be suitable for this task.

Comment: ya i can fetch/build data in that format  as you are suggesting , then it will be a supervised learning problem right? if YES then can you suggest me any model that can predict future spins.

Comment: Yaa than It will become supervised Learning problem! Pleas see the kaggle link I have attached in the answer.In that notebook I make a fucntion in which you can train your data on more than 15 models and got accuracy in return. than see w.r.t the accuracy which model is doing well. before training any model on your data it is not possible to select the best.

Comment: kindly upvote notebook and answer (mark as tick as well ) if it is useful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The existing version of your problem perfectly falls under the definition of a time series modelling since your data is a sequence taken at successive equally spaced points in time. Considering the fact that you have already tried time series I would recommend you to try deep learning based approach which can mine of temporal patters in the data. RNNs with LSTM units could be one option which could give it a try. For more details regarding RNN with LSTM implementation in keras please refer to [Time Series Prediction with LSTM Recurrent Neural Networks in Python with Keras](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/).

Comment: sure i will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

No one can answer your question with the informations you gave.

Since we are talking about a time series, you could apply many models that fits under the category "Machine Learning" like ARIMA, non-linear curve fitting, Exponential smoothing and so on.
On the "Deep Learning" side you can apply some declination of Recurrent Neural Network or even a standard Multilayer Perceptron with a windowing approach.

What I'm trying to say is that you have tons of possibilities but you first have to learn a little bit of background and than experiment with your specific dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the response,
I had tried ARIMA  and also Facebooks fbprophet model for time series Analysis
but that doesn't work.
what i'm confused about is that "can i predict future spins" ?

Comment: How can we know if we don't see the full data or at least a plot? The fact that fbprophet didn't work suggests that this is not a trivial problem but this doesn't mean it's impossible. On Stack Overflow it's good practice to include in the question the work that has already been done, so try to edit it including everything you already tried.